# OneLogin for Java: how to handle different environments?

Tags: java, saml-2.0, onelogin

I assume this must be a common scenario, but I need to support SSO/SLO in different environments using different domains. Currently I solve this by using multiple properties files:

```
onelogin.saml.dev.properties
onelogin.saml.uat.properties
onelogin.saml.prod.properties
```

In reality though, all settings are exactly the same except for the domain names. For example:

```
onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.url = https://dev.myapp.com/SsoAuthentication
onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.url = https://uat.myapp.com/SsoAuthentication
onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.url = https://www.myapp.com/SsoAuthentication
```

Is there a way to use one file and just specify the environment, or root domain to use ?

Thank you,
Simon